# How to print out row of CSV file with max value in one column Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I have this data:

```
EXAMPLE_DATA = [
['time', 'age', 'height', 'width', 'ethnicity', 'religion'],
['18:42:11', '61', '153.9615', '0.8', 'Mixed', 'None'],
['18:35:00', '34', '116.4253333', '10.17', 'Mixed', 'None'],
['14:25:40', '14', '119.7673475', '65.44', 'Mixed', 'None'],
['19:39:06', '33', '145.2423535', '9.4', 'Mixed', 'None'],
['17:22:17', '66', '122.2351111', '12.4', 'Mixed', 'None'],
['13:15:00', '77', '187.4983398', '19.88', 'Mixed', 'None']
]
```

This is my code:

```
headings = ['Time', 'Age', 'Height', 'Width', 'Ethnicity', 'Religion']
rows = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for heading, row in zip(headings, rows):
    print(heading + ': ' + datafunc[row])
```

'datafunc' calls EXAMPLE_DATA[1] or EXAMPLE_DATA[2] or ([3], [4] etc) depending on which row of data I want it to output. 
If it calls EXAMPLE_DATA[1], this is the output I get:

```
Time: 18:42:11
Age: 61
Height: 153.9615
Width: 0.8
Ethnicity: Mixed
Religion: None
```

What I want to be able to do is to write code that finds the largest 'width' and then prints out not only the largest 'width' but also prints out the 'time', 'age', 'height', 'ethnicity', and 'religion' which is on the same row of data as the largest 'width.

If you need any more information please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the key argument of the `max` function to give a function that extracts from each row the value for which you want to find the max (here 3 corresponds to the column width, and is converted to a float):

```
max_row = max(EXAMPLE_DATA[1:], key=lambda row: float(row[3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find_max(data_list):
    max_row =0;
    max_width=0;
    for i in range(1,len(data_list)):
        if float(data_list[i][3]) > max_width:
            max_width = float(data_list[i][3])
            max_row = i
    return max_row

row_to_print = find_max(EXAMPLE_DATA)
list_to_print = EXAMPLE_DATA[row_to_print]

for i in range(len(headings):
    print(headings[i]+" : " + list_to_print[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EXAMPLE_DATA = [
['time', 'age', 'height', 'width', 'ethnicity', 'religion'],
['18:42:11', '61', '153.9615', '0.8', 'Mixed', 'None'],
['18:35:00', '34', '116.4253333', '10.17', 'Mixed', 'None'],
['14:25:40', '14', '119.7673475', '65.44', 'Mixed', 'None'],
['19:39:06', '33', '145.2423535', '9.4', 'Mixed', 'None'],
['17:22:17', '66', '122.2351111', '12.4', 'Mixed', 'None'],
['13:15:00', '77', '187.4983398', '19.88', 'Mixed', 'None']
]

headings = ['Time', 'Age', 'Height', 'Width', 'Ethnicity', 'Religion']
rows = max(EXAMPLE_DATA[1:], key=lambda e: float(e[3]))
print(rows)
for heading, row in zip(headings, rows):
    print(heading + ': ' + row)
```

**Output :**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
['14:25:40', '14', '119.7673475', '65.44', 'Mixed', 'None']
Time: 14:25:40
Age: 14
Height: 119.7673475
Width: 65.44
Ethnicity: Mixed
Religion: None
```